# input date is not saved while all other inputs are saved

Tags: django, date

due_date input is not saved after submitting the form / POST. Nothing is registered in the DB but no error is shown in the console as well.

All data are saved except the due_date input, I do not understand where is the error.

I tried hundreds possibilities but all of them failed. I appreciate million times your help. Thank you !!

**Model**

```
from datetime import date
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    memo = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Form**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Todo

class TodoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'memo', 'due_date', 'important']
        due_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'),
        input_formats=('%m/%d/%Y', )
        )
```

**view**

```
@login_required
def createtodo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/createtodo.html', {'form':TodoForm()})
    else:
        try:
            form = TodoForm(request.POST)
            newtodo = form.save(commit=False)
            newtodo.user = request.user
            newtodo.save()
            
            return redirect('currenttodos')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'todo/createtodo.html', {'form':TodoForm(), 'error':'Bad data passed in. Try again.'})
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="due_date">Due</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="due_date" value="{{todo.due_date}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="memo">Memo</label>
                    <textarea name="memo" class="form-control" id="memo" ></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="important" class="form-check-input" id="important">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="important">Important</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your form code for next:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Todo

class TodoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'memo', 'due_date', 'important']
        due_date = forms.DateField(
            input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
            widget=forms.DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'type': 'date',
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
                format='%Y-%m-%d'
            )
        )
```

Because HTML `<input type='date'>` element takes a date value in the next format `YYYY-mm-dd`
Check NOTE here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value

Comment: Thank you, but your solution didn't solve the issue. I still have same issue.

Comment: @HB21, it works with your code `%m/%d/%Y` or only with my version `%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was missing ***.value*** in the HTML date input tag so `value="{{todo.due_date}}"` should be `value="{{todo.due_date.value}}"`

Comment: I just wrote one more version. But the problem turned out to be something else :D